# I want to make secureTextEntry my text input in react native true, But when write the first letter is false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I want to make the first letter in my text input is visible for a second.
so I want to make secureTextEntry my text input in react native true, But when write the first letter is false

I tried that,
   `// secureTextEntry: state.password.length ? true : false`
but it didn't work

Here is my Code,

```
   const [state, setstate] = useState({
     email: '',
     password: '',
  });

<Input
          options={{
            placeholder: t('password'),
            // secureTextEntry: state.password.length ? true : false,
            secureTextEntry: true,
            value: state.password,
            ref: (ref) => {
              refs.password = ref;
            },
            onChangeText: (val) => setstate((old) => ({...old, password: val})),
            onSubmitEditing: submitHandler,
          }}
        />
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I want to make the first letter in my text input is visible for a second

Comment: Please show your code in `Input` component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to make the first letter in my text input is visible for a second

```
secureTextEntry: state.password.length > 0,

onChangeText: (val) =>
  val.length === 1
    ? setTimeout(
        setstate((old) => ({ ...old, password: val })),
        1000
      )
    : setstate((old) => ({ ...old, password: val })),
```